# I need a SQL Query split delimited data in column to multiple columns in SQL sever 2012

Tags: sql-server

My data is in stored in table in following format:-

aa|bbbbb|ccc (Here there are 3 strings split by 2 '|')

sssss|zzz|aaaaa|ffff (Here there are 4 strings separated by  3 '|')

**Table**

```
aa|bbbbb|ccc

sssss|zzz|aaaaa|ffff
```

**Output should be as follows**

```
|*col1|-------- |col2|--------- |col3|--------- |col4*|

|sssss|-----     |zzz|----------        |aaaaa|-------|ffff|

|aa|----------|bbbbb|   --------|ccc|       ----------|NULL|
```

Comment: Storing data in such a Format is very bad db design. Read about normalization

Comment: Pls format text (see stackoverflow tour), add sample data, add what have you tried and result obtained, add expected results .  Using text formatted pls (not images)

Comment: Then try using search (in google and stackoverflow) to see if there is already a similar solution (eg. try MSSQL SPLIT COLUMN)

Comment: IS that a real time scenario implemented in your project

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql to split one column to 3 column delimiter by '|':

```
    select 
        col1,
        substring(B.COL2,0,CHARINDEX('|', B.COL2)) col2,
        substring(B.COL2,1+CHARINDEX('|', B.COL2),len(B.COL2)-CHARINDEX('|', B.COL2)) col3
        FROM
(
    select 
        substring(a.string,0,CHARINDEX('|', A.string)) col1,
        substring(a.string,1+CHARINDEX('|', A.string),len(a.string)-CHARINDEX('|', A.string)) col2
    from
    (
        select 'aa|bbbbb|ccc' string
    ) A
) b
```